# Compute first few principal components of a large data set, quickly

Tags: r, performance, package, pca

I'm working with large data sets (matrices of dimension 6000 x 3072), and using the `prcomp()` function to do my principal component calculation. However, the function is extremely slow. Even using the rank argument which can limit the number of components to calculate, it still takes 7-8 minutes. Now, I need to calculate principal components 45 times, as well as do some other intermediate calculation that take a few minutes on their own. So I don't want to sit staring at my computer screen for 8-9 hours on this simple analysis.

What are the fastest principal component analysis packages, I can use to speed up the process. I only need to calculate the first 20, so, so the majority of the computation can be ignored.

Comment: Questions asking for package recommendations are off-topic for the site. However, you can try to use a `data.table` way so as to leverage `data.table`'s speed. I don't know how fast this is but it might help: `FactoMineR::PCA()`

Comment: @NelsonGon - Thank you for the reply. Is there a place that I can ask where this might be more relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe over at cross-validated(not sure). Try the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299460/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-first-two-principal-components-in-r) and there are a couple of packages used in the answers.

Comment: You can run 45 parallel jobs and finish your tasks in 8 minutes (if you have access to multiple cores)

Comment: https://github.com/yixuan/rARPACK/blob/master/man/eigs.Rd ?

Comment: Use the Math Kernel Library (MKL). You can either install Microsoft R Open or follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090206/linking-intels-math-kernel-library-mkl-to-r-on-windows. Hope it helps you.

Comment: https://privefl.github.io/blog/fast-r-functions-to-get-first-principal-components/

Comment: You might also rewrite / rephrase your question so it better fits the format here on SO. Possibly asking about "methodology" rather than recommendations for software could be a better fit.